# Is there any way I can stop java from destroying an object

Tags: java

I want to create a java game and make it remember an object. Whenever I re-run the game, the object gets reinitialized and I lose all the data that I have stored. Is there any way I can stop java from destroying my object and reference it whenever I want, i.e, get the memory address of the object?

Comment: This is what databases of all kinds were invented for.  Look into relational, NoSQL, serialization as XML or JSON to a file, or anything else that has solved this problem.

Comment: Serialisation did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement functionality for storing a state of your game.
When you will start it again this saved state should be recreated.

As some solution, you can use [`Serialisation`](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento) for it.

**BTW** You can use common game shortcuts for saving and retreating state:

- `F5` save the game state
- `F9` revert saved state

Also, you can have a look to [State GoF pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, i used serialisation! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize your object into a file and then read it back. Your object will need to implement Serializable interface. Then you simply can do this:

```
public class MyData implements Serializable{
    int data;

    public MyData (int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Let's say we want to save our MyData object. Here is simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyData data = new MyData(5);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myobject.ser"));
    oos.writeObject(data);
    oos.close();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myobject.ser"));
    data = (MyData) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(data.data);
}
```

Remember that if you want to serialize object all fields of that object must implement Serializable interface. Also you cannot edit the class later cause then reading an object will cause an exception because it won't be the same object.

You can find more about serialization here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 1):

When you close an application the operating system will free all memory that is initalized(allocated) by the application. So if you want to find an object after you close the application you have to serialize it. Meaning the object must be kept as a byte in a file and when your aplication starts again you can initalize it from the file. Read here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOuputStream to read and save info of Object.

Answer (score 0):

When the JVM is stopped, all allocated objects are freed.
So you have to handle inside your application the persistence to avoid losing the state of your application when it is shutdown.

In a game development with state persistence, we have generally two types of save :

- the automatic save
- the user save.

The first allows the player to retrieve a state near from his last progress  without worrying about explicitly saving its party.
Automatic saves are decided by the game designer that chooses the relevant time to auto-save.

The second one allows the player to save its save when he wants to.

---

About the way to save game information, you have multiple ways to do it.

Here are 3 easy and standard ways :

- If you want to have data that may be easily readable and modifiable outside the application, you should favor the use of human readable data language such as XML or JSON.
- If you don't want data to be human readable you may use [the standard java serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).
- If you needs to have strong performance, you should use a third library
  as [fast serialization](http://ruedigermoeller.github.io/fast-serialization/) to perform the serialization.

Using a database is relevant for online games but for offline games, it is often an overhead.